# Automate file downloading using a chrome extension

Tags: python, automation, imacros

I have a .csv file with a list of URLs I need to extract data from. I need to automate the following process: (1) Go to a URL in the file. (2) Click the chrome extension that will redirect me to another page which displays some of the URL's stats. (3) Click the link in the stats page that enables me to download the data as a .csv file. (4) Save the .csv. (5) Repeat for the next n URLs.

Any idea how to do this? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hire someone to code this for you?

Comment: Perhaps you can do all the steps with 'iMacros for Chrome'. However the step #2 needs more details. What is the chrome extension you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package called mechanize. It helps you automate the processes that can be done on a browser. So check it out.I think mechanize should give you all the tools required to solve the problem.